# want to replace uuid in given url '/v2/merchants/e0cf059a-5080-40a5-aaf1-67eb866aa48f/secretKey' with '*' using python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace the uuid in the given URL `/v2/merchants/e0cf059a-5080-40a5-aaf1-67eb866aa48f/secretKey` with the `*` sign. I tried using the following regular expression, but I'm still not able to do it:

```
regex = re.sub(
    r'^[a-f0-9]{8}-?[a-f0-9]{4}-?4[a-f0-9]{3}-?[89ab][a-f0-9]{3}-?[a-f0-9]{12}',
    '*',
    '/v2/merchants/e0cf059a-5080-40a5-aaf1-67eb866aa48f/secretKey'
)
```

It returns the original string `/v2/merchants/e0cf059a-5080-40a5-aaf1-67eb866aa48f/secretKey`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `^` character at the beginning of the regular expression. It matches the start of the string, but the UUID is not at the start of the URL, therefore the regex doesn't match and the string is unchanged.

See https://regex101.com/r/7pHLBX/1